# Using single cloud formation script to create more then 2 ec2 instance and attach different Security group

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have a situation were i need to use single cloudformation script to create ec2 instance, each ect instance will have its own SG and rules example
ec2 1 , SG1 (2 ports open any 22 80 etc)
ec2 2 , SG2 (3 ports not same as above)
ec2 3 , SG3  (4 ports not same as above two)

Comment: Sadly you forgot to specify what is your issue/question?

Comment: Sorry, the question is how cna i achieve using cloudformation

Comment: What is your CFN template? What have you tried? Why it does not work?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Ec2Instance: 
  Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
  Properties: 
    ImageId: 
      Fn::FindInMap: 
        - "RegionMap"
        - Ref: "AWS::Region"
        - "AMI"
    KeyName: 
      Ref: "KeyName"
    NetworkInterfaces: 
      - AssociatePublicIpAddress: "true"
        DeviceIndex: "0"
        GroupSet: 
          - Ref: "myVPCEC2SecurityGroup"
        SubnetId: 
          Ref: "PublicSubnet"

Comment: GroupSet: - Ref: "myVPCEC2SecurityGroup"   Is it possible to dynamically change Groupset using FindinMap or IF function

Comment: @PravinRC please, edit your question instead of adding this unreadable code in a comment... Btw, you didn't answer all questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in CF. You have to specify every resource you gonna create/use. But CF don't have loop functionality like terraform for this.

A cloudformation template (script you call it) allows you to create multiple resources in it not just one.